# Display database of a dynamic website in local

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

As part of my internship, I try to change the dynamic website of the company.
To do this, I installed Wamp and I transferred locally, the website of the company with filezilla
I exported three databases in the hebergeur site. I imported these databases give in phpMyadmin.

When I try to work locally, I displays errors that I can not interpret (please see the next picture).

[a link] https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6PyFANH4lYqNC1USm9oOEhEMGs/edit?usp=sharing

In (1) is normally a dropdown list that displays the zip code of cities. In local it shows me : 
(!) Notice: Undefined index: dep in D:\wamp\www\site_choix_funeraire\points-vente.php on line 282 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFuction

When I click on the map, for example, the postal code 76 (see the rag (2) in the first photo) it shows me the next photo

[a link] https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6PyFANH4lYqZWFZQTItdmhRS0E/edit?usp=sharing

I think the site does not read from the database. When I imported the database (the .Sql) in phpMyAdmin, it is necessary to add another setting to the site to tell him to point to the database or is this done systematically?

What do you think about the problem and the display ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the same username and password combination on your local machine to let the php script access the database, also the host needs to be `localhost` when you have your site running on WAMP

The error in (1) is shown because dept is not declared in your array

Comment: > The same username and password combination on your local machine
> the host needs to be localhost.
Yes, I understand.  In what place can i change these settings?
this is done at the interface phpMyadmin or there is a special configuration file. If this is the case, how to find this file? Thank you very much.

Comment: The same username and password combination on your local machine > the host needs to be localhost. Yes, I understand. In what place can i change these settings? this is done at the interface phpMyadmin or there is a special configuration file. If this is the case, how to find this file? Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope you still need the answer. I don't know the setup of your application but somewhere in all your application files there is something like config.php or config.inc or what extension the original developer has given it. You can change the host in that file no need to change it in PHPMyAdmin